# Allowing Developer Access tokens for an api secured with Auth0

Tags: api, architecture, oauth-2.0, auth0

I have used Auth0 for a while with success, I recently came across a new challenge: allowing external developers to access my API with credentials provided by my web app.

The current system comprises of:

- a Web App (not a SPA currently) with Auth0 log in
- a back end API with Auth0 api authentication

Currently there is a single client in Auth0. The user logs in on the website and when they call the API via the website the token is passed along in the headers.

My question is: what is the best way to allow developers to request direct access to the api, in a self service manner on my website?

I see two paths forward, either create a client for each developer application via the Auth0 management API (github style), or request a token on behalf of the developer with a VERY long lifespan (like AppVeyor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that your API provides functionality and/or resources that are associated or owned by an end-user, and you want to allow other application to also access this data on behalf of each end-user. <sub>If this isn't the case, and you API is general-purpose and does not require the notion of an end-user identity then other approaches like API keys could also meet your requirements.</sub>

Considering the end-user delegation scenario, the approach I would recommend would be going with the creation of separate client applications within Auth0. Like you said, you could automate this process through the Management API so that this process could be handled in a self-service way. Despite being self-service, the application that enabled the registration could still apply constraints in order to make sure only eligible developers could obtain the necessary information to then obtain access tokens to access the API.

This has the benefit that if you wanted to stop an existing developer from using your API you could just remove the associated client application and they wouldn't be allowed to request access tokens anymore and the ones they already had would be short lived and soon expire. This requirement is more complex to implement when using long-lived tokens because they would need to be revoked/blacklisted.

---

A final note, if these applications don't require to act on behalf an end-user when calling your API and you would prefer to still accept access tokens instead of using a different approach like API keys, then you can consider registering client applications meant to use the [client credentials grant](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/grant/client-credentials).

Comment: That's great, thanks, your assumption about the API providing functionality and resources owned by the end user is correct. This is the advice I was looking for.